# KeyError: '[] not found in axis' in dataframes with same length

Tags: pandas

I have n dataframes with timeseries data. One of them has higher granularity than others, so I fixed it using drop() in Pandas. To exemplify consider the three dataframes data1, data2, data3, where data3 has higher granularity. So, what I do is:

```
while exceeding data is found:
   data3.drop([i], inplace=True)
```

After this process, I check the length of all dataframes and they have equal size, which means that the previous process was successful. If I understood correctly, pandas reassign the index for me when performing `inplace=True`.

But again when I try to exclude some duplicate data like this (after the previous process):

```
while duplicate data:
   data1.drop([j], inplace=True)
   data2.drop([j], inplace=True)
   data3.drop([j], inplace=True)
```

The following error appear whiling performing drop in data3:

```
'{} not found in axis'.format(labels[mask]))
KeyError: '[37621] not found in axis'
```

I'm sure that the length of data is higher than 37621

UPDATE: The dataframes are 1 dimensional data with size 44700.

Comment: You don't have value `37621` in that axis.

Comment: Well, suppose that I have 5 rows in my data1, if I drop one (says, line 4) and all the others dataframes has length 4, I do have 4 in the axis in data1, right? Because that's my case.

Comment: My bad, looking at the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) of `pandas.DataFrame.drop`, I think you are right.

Comment: Could you check by adding `print(len(data3.index))` before `data3.drop([j], inplace=True)` and see the output?

Comment: It shows me the total length of the dataframe. The same can be get with `len()` which is 44700

Comment: Could it be the reason that `37621` has been dropped before?  What does `print(j in data3.index)` show?

Comment: Yes, that is my assumption once that the original 37621 was dropped before, but I guess that pandas reassign all the indexes. data3.index is not an iterable object.

Comment: No, pandas doesn't reassign the indexes after drop. If you want to, do `data3 = data3.drop([j], inplace=True).reset_index(drop=True)`.

Comment: So, I guess that the answer to my question is to find rows that were already dropped, once that the order (indexed) are quite important for me.